# Why won't float display properly?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying save and retrieve a float using core data. The app is running, but I am getting these strange random numbers (I can tell they're random in some capacity because they change each time I run the app) where my float values should be. For example, -1547077968 instead of just 0. Is it possible that the values are not saving to core data properly? Am I not retrieving them correctly? This code is from the view controller where the user adds a book:

```
 func createBook() {
            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Book", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
            let book = Book(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
            book.name = bookNameTextField.text
            book.author = authorTextField.text
            book.numberOfPages = numberOfPagesTextField.text.toInt()!
            book.pagesRead = 0.0 as Float
            book.timeRead = 0.0 as Float
            managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
        }
```

Here I am passing information from a TableViewController to a detail view:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showBookDetail" {
            let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            let book: AnyObject = addBookViewController.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Book
            var detailViewController:BookDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BookDetailViewController
            detailViewController.title = book.name
            detailViewController.pagesReadText = "\(book.pagesRead)"
            detailViewController.timeReadText = "\(book.timeRead)"
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Also, when I segue by tapping on a cell, the app segues twice, so that there are two View Controllers that look exactly the same in a sequence, when I have only set up one on my storyboard. I have checked that and my segue identifier matches with the one in my prepareForSegue block. I also have made sure that I set the attributes pagesRead and timeRead as floats. My apologies for the lack of pictures. I didn't have enough reputation points to post them. Here is the code from the detail view if it helps:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pagesReadLabel: UILabel!


  @IBOutlet weak var timeReadLabel: UILabel!

    var pagesReadText = String()
    var timeReadText = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pagesReadLabel.text = pagesReadText
        timeReadLabel.text = timeReadText
    }
```

I don't know why the IBOutlets formatted the way they did in my post but they are formatted correctly in my code.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question completely. Where do you see those random numbers? At the time when you read back from your database? numberOfPagesTextField or all the other fields as well?

Comment: I'm seeing these numbers when I run the app in the simulator where the UILables are for the values associated with numberOfPages and timeRead—any value that is stored as a float. Sorry for not being clearer before. When I print them to the console, the correct values are printed, it's just that the label in the simulator shows the random values.

Comment: Now I understand. viewDidLoad is executed earlier than you assign the strings so your vars are not initizalized. Put the pagesReadLabel.text = pagesReadText timeReadLabel.text = timeReadText lines just inside viewWillApear(). I am sure if you stop at those lines and you print out the value of pagesReadText it will be incorrect. To be honest I do not understand why it happens earlier.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a bunch. Do you have idea why I'm having this other issue? The one where two view appear? When I segue a new view appears and then it quickly pops over to another one.

Comment: I guess if you comment out the override func prepareForSegue function it will pop twice still. I am just guessing here but it seems that you have two segue links on two different objects and they invoke segue twice. Other guess that you have some code at didSelectRowAtIndexPath which segues and have a segue connection on IB in parallel.